# How to generate composite graph from .jtl file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

We have .jtl file from a test and we want to create composite graph for the test. We need  Active Threads Over Time and Response Times vs Threads graph.

Could you please help to create a composite graph using the jtl file.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Composite Graph from [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph/).

Put the jar file in the `/lib/ext` directory and then restart the JMeter.

After that, you will be able to see your jtl file through Composite Graph listener.

Comment: Thanks Jahan. We have installed the jar file but while creating composite graph Active Threads Over Time graph is showing but Response Times vs Threads graph is not showing in Test plan.

Comment: Did you add it to your test plan before starting the test? Otherwise, the rows will not be shown in the selector panel. Please, see the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: No. We have only the jtl file from the test

Comment: Please have a look on this guide: [How to use the Composite Graph](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-composite-graph-plugin-in-jmeter/)